# How to append numpy array inside loop and save to file

Tags: pandas, file, numpy, while-loop

I have written below code and at the end I want to append two array in a single buffer.
I want to save to text file.
Here is my code :

```
t=0
while(t>=0 and t<len(nav_time)):
  if nav_time[t]>70000 and nav_time[t]<86400:
      one_time=nav_time[t]
     # print one_time
  if nav_time[t]>=0 and nav_time[t]<70000:
      sec_time=nav_time[t]+86400
      #print sec_time
  total_time=np.append(one_time,sec_time)  # only stores two values not all values
  t=t+1
```

## example data

```
    Nav_time
   86399
86399.20313
86399.40625
86399.60156
86399.80469
0.003574
0.203574
0.403574
0.603574
0.803574
1.003575
1.203575
```

Comment: NumPy and append seldom go in the same sentence. Why not extend a list and create an array at the very end?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ .Would you tell me the step. How to proceed

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with expected output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ .Actually unable to upload data.

Comment: I don't want your data, I want an _example_. Please make up something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 lists for one_time and sec_time and append them after your for loop.
Here is a sample

```
t=0
# Create one_time and sec_time as list 
one_time = []
sec_time = []
while(t>=0 and t<len(nav_time)):
  if nav_time[t]>70000 and nav_time[t]<84600:
      one_time.append(nav_time[t])
     # print one_time
  if nav_time[t]>=0 and nav_time[t]<70000:
      sec_time.append(nav_time[t]+86400)
      #print sec_time
  #total_time=np.append(one_time,sec_time)  # only stores two values not all values
  t=t+1

# Concatenating the 2 lists, this will append sec_time after one_time in a single row.
total_time = np.concatenate((one_time, sec_time), 0)

# Saving to fileName.txt. This creates file with 1 column with multiple rows.
np.savetxt('fileName.txt', total_time, fmt='%f')
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is named `nav_time` with a column named `Nav_time`, this will filter your values.

```
filter1 = nav_time.where(~(nav_time.Nav_time > 84600)).dropna()
filter2 = np.where(filter1 > 70000,filter1,filter1+86400)

np.savetxt('file.txt', filter2)
```

Comment: @ DJK. In this process I am missing some data